# How to check if there are multiple versions of PHP installed on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04

How to know if I have both php5.3 and php5.5 installed in my system? How to delete php5.3 if it is there and configuring Apache2 to work with php5.5?

Comment: You can echo `phpinfo()` or `phpversion()` and see what they say.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 -- is the header of phpversion. But on php -v in terminal it shows php5.5.21

Comment: Ok so you know that you have two versions installed!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you have a Linux environment, you can run this on your console:

```
locate bin/php
```

And then for anything that looks like a PHP binary, get the version. The output for me for the above is:

```
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project1/webapp/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project1/webapp-backup/vendor/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/Development/Personal/Project2/app/vendor/bin/phpunit
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php-cgi
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php-config
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/phpize
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php5
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi
/usr/local/bin/php-config
/usr/local/bin/php53
/usr/local/bin/phpize
/usr/sbin/php5dismod
/usr/sbin/php5enmod
/usr/sbin/php5query
```

Out of those, there are a few that look like PHP binaries. So let's get the version for each:

```
/home/xx/php-threaded/bin/php -v
/usr/bin/php -v
/usr/bin/php5 -v
/usr/local/bin/php53 -v
```

That will give you the versions of PHP you have installed.

I wouldn't bother deleting an old version, it might remove files that will stop things working. You can just configure the console version, or the Apache version, to use the version you want.

---

In answer to your supplementary question: it seems that you've followed [the instructions here](http://www.dev-metal.com/how-to-setup-latest-version-of-php-5-5-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) to add an unofficial repo to your version of Ubuntu, since the standard repo does not support 5.5.

We discovered together that the way to get it working was first to upgrade Apache from 2.2 to 2.4:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade apache2
```

It should be noted that this *can* cause some vhost repair to be required, as some Apache directives changed in this version. Once you have done that, you can get the new version of `mod_php`:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Comment: Usually multiple PHP versions can be found with the whereis command: `whereis php`.

Answer (score 91):

I use the following command to view installed PHP versions in Ubuntu:

```
sudo update-alternatives --list php
```

Second way go to `php` directory where all PHP version configuration file stored:

```
cd /etc/php 
dir
```

Output:

```
 > 5.6  7.0  7.1
```

Answer (score 36):

To check your installed versions type:

`cd /etc/php`

in your terminal to go to the configuration folder of your PHP installations and then you type:

`ls`

The output will be the folders that corresponds to the versions installed in your machine. In my case the command outputs:

```
5.6 7.0 7.1
```

Comment: Simple and effective :-)

Comment: Not always true, even if you have many versions in /etc/php/, it doesn't mean you have many php versions installed.

If you see only "mods-available" in php version folder, for example /etc/php/5.6/mods-available, then php5.6 isn't installed.

You should have at least "cli" or "fpm" if that version is installed.

Try *update-alternatives --display php* to list available php versions.

Comment: or you can directly use `ls /etc/php`

Answer (score 33):

I am always using this command to see list of PHP versions and also for switching one version to another install PHP version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Answer (score 7):

You can run this on your console:

```
find / -name php | grep bin
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following to view installed php versions in Ubuntu:

`sudo dpkg --list | grep ' php[0-9]\.[0-9] '`

Answer (score 3):

> Get a list of all installed packages and filter installed PHP versions:

`sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | cut -d / -f 1 | grep ^php[0-9].[0-9]$;`

or

`sudo apt list --installed 2>/dev/null | cut -d / -f 1 | grep ^php[0-9].[0-9]$ | xargs;`

> if you really need to get only installed PHP versions without unnecessary.

Or

`sudo update-alternatives --list php;`

Answer (score 1):

I have nextcloud in cyberpanel, This worked for me, cd to public_html:

```bash
sudo -u webuser /usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/php occ files:scan -v --all
```

found above PHP location by:

```
locate bin/php
```

for locate to work:

```
apt install plocate
```